# Comparing values from different tuples, list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have two lists of tuples:

```
old = [('6.454', '11.274', '14')] 
new = [(6.2845306, 11.30587, 13.3138)]
```

I'd want to compare each value from the same position (`6.454` against `6.2845306` and so on) and if value from the `old` tuple is greater then value from the `new` tuple, I print it.

The net effect should be then:

```
6.454, 14
```

I did it using simple `if` statement

```
if float(old[0][0]) > float(new[0][0]):
    print old[0][0],
if float(old[0][1]) > float(new[0][1]):
    print old[0][1],
if float(old[0][-1]) > float(new[0][-1]):
    print marathon[0][-1]
```

Since there are always 3 or 2-element tuples, it's not a big problem to use slicing here but I'm looking for more elegant solution, which is list comprehension. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Having a list which holds only a single tuple seems like a bit of a redundant data structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[o for o,n in zip(old[0], new[0]) if float(o) > float(n)]
```

This should work?

Answer (score 2):

So you want something like:

```
print [o for o,n in zip(old[0],new[0]) if float(o) > float(n)]
```

Answer (score 2):

use the built-in function `zip`:

```
for x,y in zip(old[0],new[0]):
    if float(x)>float(y):
        print x,
   ....:         
6.454 14
```

If the tuples are of unequal length then `zip` will only compare up to the shorter of the two, you can handle that case using [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

help on `zip`:

```
In [90]: zip?
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
String Form:<built-in function zip>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:
zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]

Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(old)):
    for j in range(len(old[i]):
        if old[i][j]>new[i][j]:
            print old[i][j]
```